# Why are some of my CPU cores running only at a fraction of their factory frequency and some even above?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7, overclocking, cpu-speed, underclock

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit and I have an Intel Core i7-4930K CPU @ 3.40 GHz nominal frequency. Please have a look at this CPUID HWMonitor output:

[image: CPU frequencies]

Cores #1, #3, #4 are running at only 1201 MHz, while cores #0, #2, #5 are at 3502 MHz.

**Question:** Why is this the case and how can I permanently set all cores to the maximum permissible value?

**Motivation:** I need to run computationally intense FDTD simulations and despite having achieved some degree of CPU parallelization by [automatic module jitting](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit-module.html), there is no noticeable acceleration (take a look at cores #0, #2, #5, #6, #8, #10):

[image: CPU usage]

These screenshots were taken at the same time while running the simulation, i.e. under load.

Also, a temperature reading `CPUTIN` permanently reads values way over 100 °C, despite setting all fan speeds to maximum:

[image: CPU temperature]

Could it be that the CPU is throttling due to thermal issues? Are 800-900 RPM (i.e. only 15 Hz) really typical values for max. speeds? This looks more like idling speed...

Comment: Why would you want to set all cores to the maximum permissible value? It's just going to use more power and the CPU will increase clock speed when it's needed anyway.

Comment: @mtak Good question, I've added an explanation to the question

Comment: Nice explanation. However, based on your screenshot, there is no need to increase clock speed, since the utilization isn't even over 50%. Are you sure that your process is bottle-necked by CPU and not something else? Not saying that there have never been 
problems with Intel microcode, but based on this info, it seems you are not maxing out your CPU.

Comment: @mtak Hi, what else could be a bottleneck? I have 32 GB RAM (of which only 16 GB are usable thanks to Microsoft's stupid Windows 7 Home Premium castration policy). The simulation files are on an old HDD (not SSD), but this shouldn't make any difference since everything lives in RAM, right?

Comment: CPUTIN is so high compared to all other values, its fairly safe to think that value is being misread (maybe it reports in F by default, 104F = 41C so its a likely explenation). Use something else (Prime95 for example) to stress all your cores. If that works and keeps your CPU humming at 3.4 - 3.9Ghz per core, its your Python code thats the bottleneck as its not properly threading.

Comment: Also, your VCore is low(iirc, your cpu should go upto 1.4V without overvolting) and so is your total package power. Its reading 46W while TDP for your CPU is 140W. You should really try a real stress test like Prime95 and see what values you get then.

Comment: Python isn't the best multi-threader around, unless you specifically develop for it (and not just slap on a multithreading module). @Silbee suggestion is a good idea to narrow down the problem. Also, HDDs are unimaginably slow, so unless your files fit in your RAM filesystem cache, there is a good chance that your disk _is_ the bottleneck. It'd probably be a good idea to start integrating an application profiler, to see what is slowing down your app. I can't make any guesses about Windows filesystem caching, being more of a Unix guy myself.

Comment: You cannot “magically” parallelize code. There’s real work involved and it may not be possible at all (or only partially). // To check if there is a problem with your CPU, use Silbee’s suggestion and run Prime95.

Comment: @Silbee °F/°C sounds very plausible. Okay, I've set all limiters in the "AI Tweaker" of the Asus 4608 BIOS to maximum without manually changing or setting any multiplier/voltage/current values and run Prime95 while watching HWMonitor readings, see updated screenshots in the question

Comment: @Silbee Also, VCore and package power peak at only about 1.25 V and 112 W with clocks dropping to only 2.4 GHz. Doesn't this look like a thermal problem?

Comment: Is it be safe to run this CPU at close to 100 °C (like *permanently*)?

Comment: @sarahslvmn It does look like a thermal issue. And no, its not advisable to run your CPU close to those temps for extended periods of time. You definitely want to tackle whatever cooling issues you have. Look like a good start would be to check your current CPU cooler and if its upto the job. If its rated to cool 140W+, you'll want to reapply thermal paste and test again. Ultimately you might have to change CPU cooler and add additional fans. And, now you also know your python code isnt threading well either :) Needs more jitter tuning...